# libreria de Javascript que convierta pdf en jpg/png

Tags: javascript, imagen, pdf, librería

¿alguna librería que conozcan que convierta pdf en una imagen de Buena calidad? encontré una llamada pdf.js pero las saca de mala calidad ¿conocen otra Liberia  o sabes como moverle a la calidad de imagen que se descarga en esta libreria? esto es para javascript

agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo donde te salga la imagen de mala calidad? yo estuve probando este ejemplo: http://usefulangle.com/post/24/pdf-to-jpeg-png-with-pdfjs y si aumento el tamaño del canvas la imagen sale de la resolución que yo quiera

Comment: ohh ya, ¿me podrias decir donde fue que hiciste el aumento del tamaño del canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, no puedo mostrarlo en un snippet, porque PDF.js hace un request de tipo POST para traerse el PDF y estos snippets no lo permiten. Pero te dejé un ejemplo en

https://examples.ffflabs.com/pdf2png.html

Básicamente, creas un canvas con el ancho deseado:

```
<body>
    <div id="pdf-main-container">
        <a id="download-image" href="#">Download PNG</a>
        <canvas id="pdf-canvas" width="800"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ahí le puse 800px de ancho.

Ese canvas después exporta la imagen cuando el link de download recibe la salida de `canvas.toDataUrl()` y el atributo `download` que le indica al browser que debe descargar el link en vez de seguirlo:

```
$("#download-image").on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('href', __CANVAS.toDataURL()).attr('download', 'page.png');
});
```

Lo importante es que la dimensión original del PDF se redimensiona al tamaño del contenedor canvas. Si el contenedor es muy chico, se perderá calidad.

Todo lo anterior puede hacerse también con un PDF de varias páginas

https://examples.ffflabs.com/pdf-to-png2.html

Sólo que el paginador va cargando una página a la vez. Si quisieras exportar todo el documento habría que modificar el script y posiblemente alterar la altura del canvas.